# How to spit a list without double-quotes

Tags: clojure

I have the following line in my code:

```
(spit path (prn-str job-data))
```

It does it's work well execpt for one thing, every item in the list are put between double-quotes...

```
( ":a" ":b" ":a" )
```

the expected result that I'd like to have

```
( :a :b :a )
```

How to get the expected result?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What's happening

The issue isn't that the items are being put in double quotes *per se* but that they're strings (as opposed to the keywords you're expecting).

[`prn-str`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/prn-str), which is ultimately based on [`pr`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/pr), prints objects "in a way that objects can be read by the reader". This means strings are printed in double-quotes - otherwise the reader wouldn't be able to tell strings from symbols, or read strings with whitespace in them. See [here](http://clojure.org/reader) for more information on Clojure's reader.

[`println`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/println) and [`print`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/print), on the other hand, are intended to "produce output for human consumption" and do not put strings in double-quotes. This is why you're seeing the difference in output between `prn-str` and `println`.

You can verify this with `class`. If you try `(-> job-data first class)` the answer will be either `java.lang.String` or `clojure.lang.Keyword`.

Here are some examples demonstrating the different behaviors of the printing functions when used with keywords and strings:

```
(def str-job-data '(":a" ":b" ":c"))
(def key-job-data '(:a :b :c))

;; `println` prints both keywords and strings without quotes
(with-out-str (println str-job-data)) ;=> "(:a :b :c)\n"
(with-out-str (println key-job-data)) ;=> "(:a :b :c)\n"

;; `prn-str` prints the strings in quotes but the keywords without quotes
(prn-str str-job-data) ;=> "(\":a\" \":b\" \":c\")\n"
(prn-str key-job-data) ;=> "(:a :b :c)\n"
```

#### How to change it

Now for possible solutions. If you were expecting `job-data` to contain keywords then the right fix is most likely to modify `job-data`. However, I can't offer much guidance here without knowing more about how `job-data` is produced.

If for some reason you can't modify `job-data` (for instance, if it's produced by code you don't control) and you want to write keywords wherever it contains keyword-like strings then something like @maxthoursie's suggestion is probably your best bet. (You could hypothetically just switch to `print` or `println` but that could have undesirable effects on how other objects are printed).

```
(defn keyword-string->keyword [s]
  (keyword (subs s 1)))

(spit path (prn-str (map keyword-string->keyword job-data)))
```

If `job-data` might contain objects other than keyword-like strings you could apply the function only when appropriate.

```
(defn convert-job-data [obj]
  (if (and (string? obj)
           (= (.charAt obj 0) \:))
    (keyword-string->keyword obj)
    obj))

(spit path (prn-str (map convert-job-data job-data)))
```

Of course, if the file you're writing is for human consumption anyway and all this business about the reader is irrelevant you could trivially make your own `println-str`:

```
(defn println-str [& more]
  (with-out-str (apply println more)))

(spit path (println-str job-data))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing job-data is not what you expect it to be.

```
user=> (prn-str '(:a :b :c))
"(:a :b :c)\n"
```

If you do have a list with strings that looks like keywords, and you would like to convert it to keywords, you could use something like

```
 (map (comp keyword #(subs % 1)) '(":a" ":b" ":c"))
```

Which skips the : of each element, and then converts it to a keyword.

```
user=> (prn-str (map (comp keyword #(subs % 1)) '(":a" ":b" ":c")))
"(:a :b :c)\n"
```

Comment: If I (println job-data) it prints without the double-quotes. To me it seems like the prn-str adds the quotes on the items. But without prn-str it only prints LazySeq and that is worse. :-)